# 80s Robot Cartoon where giant robot is controlled by kid with lunchbox

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I need help remembering an 80s cartoon show that was about a giant blue robot that was controlled by a little kid using either a lunchbox or a briefcase. I remember the robot had the number 33 painted on it in yellow letters and also that the eyes of the robot were yellow.

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, you can mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be ***[The New Adventures of Gigantor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458218/)*** (aka *New Tetsujin-28*)...?

From IMDB:

> At the beginning of the 21st century, scientists found that with new computers and super alloys, they could build an even bigger, faster Gigantor. They built the new Gigantor.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Adventures_of_Gigantor):

> *New Tetsujin-28* (太陽の使者 鉄人28号, Taiyō no Shisha Tetsujin Nijūhachi-gō, lit. Solar Messenger Iron Man #28) is a 1980 Japanese Mecha Animated series produced by Tokyo Movie Shinsha, and a modern style remake of Mitsuteru Yokoyama's manga Tetsujin 28-go.[3](https://youtu.be/AuceLU556dU?t=867) It was directed by Tetsuo Imazawa and produced by both Shigeru Akagawa and Toru Horikoshi. It aired on Nippon Television from October 3, 1980 to September 25, 1981 with a total count of 51 episodes. Fred Ladd and TMS converted the series into *The New Adventures of Gigantor*, which was broadcast on the Sci-Fi Channel in the United States from September 9, 1993 to June 30, 1997.

As you can see in the video below, the the giant robot is blue with yellow eyes and the number "28" printed on both arms (in yellow), and a boy is shown controlling it with control panel contained within a briefcase around the 14:27 mark.